Is hono RPC features (using hono/client) compatible with Expo?
I tried to use hono/client package to benefit from hono native RPC features in my new react native expo project.
import { AppType } from "../../../backend/src";
import { hc } from 'hono/client';

export const client = hc<AppType>(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL!);

I successfully installed hono (which is present in my node_modules folder)
This import gives me the following issue:
Unable to resolve module hono/client from node_modules.
I tried with multiple versions of hono, removing node_modules, clear cache and reinstall packages, same issue...
Is hono not working in react native environment ?
